# Can docker compose skip build if the image is present?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is it possible to run `docker-compose up` in such a way that it will only build if the image isn't present in the repository?

I'm working on a test scenario that will run in two different environments: locally on a laptop, and on a server as part of test automation. My docker-compose file looks something like this:

```
services:
  my-service1:
    build: "./local-repo1"
    image: "image1"
  my-service2:
    build: "./local-repo2"
    image: "image2"
  ...
```

If I run it locally where the local-repo directories exist it runs fine. If I try to run it on the server where it instead pulls from a docker repository it complains that it cannot find the build path. If I take out the `build` property it runs fine on the server, but then it won't run locally unless I build the images beforehand.

Is there a way to make it only try to build if the image doesn't already exist? If not I can try some workarounds, but I'd prefer to use just one docker-compose file that handles each case.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use `docker-compose pull` to fetch images. Then if they are present already, Compose will not try to build them again.

To be really sure to avoid rebuilds, you can use `--no-build`.

```
docker-compose pull
docker-compose up -d --no-build
```

Your real problem is that you are specifying a build context, but then trying to use docker-compose without that build context being present.

When docker-compose runs, *even if it has no plan to do a build*, it will verify the build context at least exists. If it doesn't, then it will fail.

All you need to do to satisfy this requirement is create an empty directory for any missing build context. That should make docker-compose happy enough to run.

```
mkdir -p local-repo1 local-repo2
```

Comment: When I try either case it still gives me the `ERROR: build path <path> either does not exist, is not accessible, or is not a valid URL.` If I run `docker images` I see the image with the same repository as the value I put in the image property in the docker-compose file, though. Does it matter that the image was not built from the directory specified in the build property, even though it has the same repository value?

Comment: Awesome, adding mock directories worked. It still feels kinda kludgy, but meh, I'll take it. Thank you!

Comment: @kallenboone Ok, I updated the answer to reflect that part too. Glad to help.

Comment: Docker verifying the build context when it is not really necessary is indeed quite confusing: see https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1973 or https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3513 or

Comment: Recent versions of docker-compose won't require the build context to exist if called with `--no-build`.

Answer (score 6):

i am using docker-compose v2.1

when we run docker compose up it check image is exist or not. if not exist then only it build that image otherwise it will skip that part

docker-compose

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  devimage:
    image: nodedockertest
    build: .
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

[image]

Comment: i hope do u get what i mean