# reuses image built by docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I built image using

`docker build -t my-image`

docker-compose.yml has

```
   django:
     build:
       context: .
       dockerfile: ./compose/django/Dockerfile-dev
    image: my-image
```

Then I run `docker-compose build`

I see `my-image` is being built again even though I built it previously.

Can an image built by `docker build` be used by `docker-compose` ?

Answer (score 1):

## What you have written

As [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#service-configuration-reference#build) say:

> If you specify image as well as build, then Compose names the built image with the webapp and optional tag specified in image:

## How to avoid this

- If you want to rebuild each time

  Build as you are, and the build artifact will be saved with the name `my-image`
- If you want to reuse the build

  Change to just specify the image to use
- If you only want to build if the image doesn't exist

  Run compose with `--no-build` as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43356880/8041461) describes