# How to make docker-compose build images not already present?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose.yaml` file with details on how to build and use 10 containers.

I ran `docker-compose build` which built 5 images successfully, but failed on the 6th.

After I corrected the problem, I re-ran `docker-compose build` hoping that docker-compose would only build missing images.  But it started building images from the beginning!

Why?

Can I get docker-compose to continue, without re-building existing images?

**Note:** The answer to the question below didn't really resolve my problem, because I'm not trying to pull the images from anywhere:

[Can docker compose skip build if the image is present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43354652/can-docker-compose-skip-build-if-the-image-is-present)

Comment: you can write `docker-compose build <service_name>` so it builds only for the given service

Comment: Okay, this is very handy to know, thanks!  But it would be nice to be able to do a `docker-compose up` and just have that figured out - doesn't seem hard.  Just need a way to specify preference for a local build.  There is a --pull option to preference pulling but no opposite to preference local, let alone local *build*.

Comment: `docker-compose` is simply delegating to Docker for building your images. When possible, it will use the Docker build cache as is the same for all other builds. If your images are being re-built each time, then Docker believes something within the build context is changing and should therefore re-build the images. Can you post the output of your `docker-compose build`?

Comment: Sorry, the output from the commands that prompted this question are long gone, but I'll post example output as soon as I see it happening again.